# Trying to push response from Axios.all to state in ComponentDidMount but getting unwanted lifecycle response

Tags: reactjs, axios, mern

With the lockdown, I'm taking the time to learn ReactJs and creating a todo app on a MERN stack.

I'm trying to use Axios.all for concurrent gets on three routes in Express.  The app is running but not returning the data to the .map method.  The code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

//  [[ MATERIAL UI COMPONENTS ]]   //
import TaskList from './TaskList';
import TaskHeader from './TaskHeader';
import { Typography, Paper, Grid, Divider } from '@material-ui/core';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';



   class Tasks extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);

            this.deleteTask = this.deleteTask.bind(this);

            this.state = {
                tasks: [],
                category: [],
                goals: []
            };
        }

        async componentDidMount() {
            const taskURI = 'http://localhost:5000/TaskData/';
            const categoryURI = 'http://localhost:5000/CategoryData/';
            const goalURI = 'http://localhost:5000/GoalData/';

            const getTasks = axios.get(taskURI);
            const getCategory = axios.get(categoryURI);
            const getGoals = axios.get(goalURI);

            axios
                .all([ getTasks, getCategory, getGoals ])
                .then(
                    axios.spread((taskData, categoryData, goalData) => {
                        this.setState({ tasks: taskData });
                        this.setState({ category: categoryData });
                        this.setState({ goals: goalData });
                    })
                )
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                });
            console.log('tasks');
            console.log(this.state.tasks);
        }

        deleteTask(id) {
            axios.delete('http://localhost:5000/TaskData/' + id).then((response) => {
                console.log(response.data);
            });

            this.setState({
                tasks: this.state.tasks.filter((cl) => cl._id !== id)
            });
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <Paper
                    style={{
                        padding: 0,
                        margin: 0,
                        height: '100vh',
                        backgroundColor: '#11233d'
                    }}
                    elevation={0}
                >
                    <Grid container justify="center" style={{ marginTop: '1rem' }}>
                        <Grid item xs={11} md={11} lg={11}>
                            <TaskHeader />
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid container justify="center" style={{ marginTop: '1rem' }}>
                        <Grid item xs={11} md={11} lg={11}>
                            <TaskList
                                tasks={this.state.tasks}
                                category={this.state.category}
                                goals={this.state.goals}
                                deleteTask={this.id}
                            />
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </Paper>
            );
        }
    }

    export default Tasks;
```

I then call another component, passing the props:

```
import React from 'react';
import Task from './Task';
//import { confirmTask } from './confirmTask';

//  [[  MATERIAL UI COMPONENTS]]
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import Divider from '@material-ui/core/Divider';
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';

// [[ FUNCTION ]] //
function TaskList({ tasks, categories, goals, removeTask }) {
    debugger;
    console.log('Length');
    console.log(tasks.length);
    console.log('Tasks array:');
    console.log(tasks);
    if (tasks.length)
        return (
            <Paper
                style={{
                    padding: 0,
                    margin: 0,
                    backgroundColor: '#23334b'
                }}
            >
                debugger;
                <h5>header</h5>
                <List>
                    {tasks.map((task, i) => (
                        <React.Fragment key={i}>
                            {/* <confirmTask checked={removeTask} /> */}
                            <Checkbox tabIndex={-1} checked={removeTask} />
                            <h5>hi</h5>
                            <Task
                                {...task}
                                key={task.userId}
                                category={categories}
                                goals={goals}
                                removeTask={removeTask}
                            />
                            <Divider style={{ backgroundcolor: '#2d418a' }} />
                        </React.Fragment>
                    ))}
                </List>
            </Paper>
        );
    return null;
}

export default TaskList;
```

Reviewing the console.log and debugger steps the first log for (this.state.tasks) shows the array of tasks in the route.  ok.
But, trying to setState, from what I have read the Lifecycle method then calls render() and the new component is called, but is not passing the state [tasks].
So the tasks.length is 0, so `tasks.map` is not called and wouldn't run because tasks is null.

The question.  How do I use setState to capture the `axios.spread` results, if I can't set use setState from within .then ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Update:
I added these console logs to track it.  The firt time the array is [], so nothing.  It then runs again as the 'ComponentDidMount' completes and has data in the array when you view the console (see screenshot below).  BUT, even though the array shows as [13] tasks.length is still failing and returning null.  ??

```
function TaskList({ tasks, categories, goals, removeTask }) {
    debugger;
    console.log('Length');
    console.log(tasks.length);
    console.log('Tasks array:');
    console.log(tasks);
    if (tasks.length)
        return (
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2y5m1.png)

Comment: Are you getting any data on console.log(this.state.tasks); ? I remember axios returns data in response.data not directly in the response.

Comment: Yes, the 'console.log(this.state.tasks);' returns the array (with 13 tasks), but is not being passed down to '<TaskList tasks={this.state.tasks}/>' in the return.  If I add a Debugger, it looks to call '<TaskList tasks={this.state.tasks}/>', passing no data before it complets the 'axios.spread' and updating the state.

Comment: "If I add a Debugger, it looks to call '<TaskList tasks={this.state.tasks}/>', passing no data before it complets the 'axios.spread' and updating the state" - That's coz initially `this.state.tasks` is an empty array `[]`. The axios calls are async and they will complete only at a later time at which point, if successful the state is updated and the component is re-rendered.

Answer (score 0):

welcome to StackOverflow. I think you might be using the axios.spread method incorrectly. It probably should be:

```
                .then(
                    axios.spread((taskData, categoryData, goalData) => {
                        this.setState({ tasks: taskData.data });
                        this.setState({ category: categoryData.data });
                        this.setState({ goals: goalData.data });
                    });
                );
```

**Disclaimer: I haven't tested it out myself.**

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  Your code makes sense.  I did update the code and tried again.  The second component is still being passed null.  The second component is still showing a length of 0.  This implies that 'tasks' is not being passed from the header component.

Comment: It should not be null since its initialized with empty array as a default value. can you please console taskData and see if has any data.

Comment: also remove `async` from `async componentDidMount()`.

Comment: Could please ensure that you have copy/pasted your code (`class Tasks`) correctly? I can't tell if you have syntax errors in there or if you have not copy/pasted your code properly.

Comment: @Clarkie - I have updated my answer above. From the image it is evident that `taskData, categoryData, goalData` are all response objects. You need to access the `data` property within the response object to access the actual data. Hope that was clear.